# Call connection string from class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So i'm really annoyed now.(Still a noob) I'm trying the use my connection string that I created in my "Common" class on my "Logon" form so that i can call a "hhrcv_logon_validation" procedure.

My quesation is how?

I've searched everywhere and yes I do get examples but I need someone to explain them better for me please? And maybe some example code as well.

I know I have to create the class for the connection string and the use that connection string to call a proc? Am i right?

This is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using CoreLab.Oracle;

namespace WMS
{
    class Common
    {
        static void connect()
        {
            // Connect
            string constr = "User ID=Password;" +
            "Password=Username;" +
            "Host="ServerName";" +
            "Pooling=true;" +
            "Min Pool Size=0;" +
            "Max Pool Size=100;" +
            "Connection Lifetime=0";
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
     }
}
```

Please help!?

---

So below is what I did with your sample code:

```
namespace WMS
{
class Common
{
    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return ConnectionString;
        }
        set
        {
            ConnectionString = "User ID=username;" +
            "Password=password;" +
            "Host=hostname;" +
            "Pooling=true;" +
            "Min Pool Size=0;" +
            "Max Pool Size=100;" +
            "Connection Lifetime=0";
        }
    }

    public static OracleConnection OpenConnection()
    {
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        return con;
    }
 }
}
```

Will this work?

And how would I then access it from a form? With this:

```
<using(var conn = Common.OpenConnection()) {
 // use it
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is working or not working?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart How do I use this connection string to call a stored procedure? Basically, I’ve got a Logon form where I want to use a stored procedure that checks if the user’s logon details are correct and do exist in the database. So where do I call this procedure? In the “Login” button? And then how exactly do I do that?

Comment: the edit that adds "So below is what I did with your sample code" has *really* broken `get`/`set` accessors

Comment: @MarcGravell If I leave it like your example code I get error:

"Error 1 'WMS.Common.ConnectionString.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern"

Comment: @Werner k - you must be using an old IDE - I'll edit my answer in a few minutes to show how to do that

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks. but I'm getting new error - An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method,or property. - at the get; set;

Comment: @Werner add "static" to the field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`constr` and `con` are scoped to the **method** in this example. If you want them to be available outside that, you'll need to store something in a *field*. For example, maybe something like:

```
class Common
{
    private string connectionString;
    public static string ConnectionString {
        get { return connectionString; }
        set { connectionString = value; }
    }
    public static DbConnection OpenConnection()
    {
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        return con;
    }
}
```

so then you would configure the connection string at some point early in your application:

```
Common.ConnectionString = ... // TODO
```

and then when you need data access:

```
using(var conn = Common.OpenConnection()) {
     // use it
}
```

I should also note that `static` state isn't always the best way to do things. It'll work, but it gives you less options later on.

Comment: @wernervdh8 well, you've made a mess of the property accessors... why did you change them from what I posted above? the `{get;set;}` should have been fine unless you're using a really old compiler. But: was there a *question* to go with that?

Comment: @WernervandenHeever see edit (above) for how to implement a basic property on older compiler versions